# Editar uma lista que está dentro de outra lista

Tags: python, lista

Preciso dividir a lista que está dentro de outra lista.

```
lista = [
    [Temperatura final = 250 k],
    [Temperatura Minima = 120 k],
    [Temperatura Maxima = 310 k]
]
```

Obter o resultado final

```
listafinal = [
    [Temperatura final, 250, k],
    [Temperatura Minima, 120, k],
    [Temperatura Maxima, 310, k]
]
```

Comment: Bom dia amigo, qual a linguagem de programação que está utilizando em seu código?

Comment: aparentemente é python, para editar um valor na lista é simples, utilize a seguinte notação: `lista[i][j] = novoValor`

Comment: Qualquer coisa, pesquise a utilização de matrizes na linguagem que você está mexendo

Comment: Sim é Python a linguagem.

Comment: Sua pergunta não está suficientemente clara. Os trechos de código que apresentou não possuem sintaxes válidas para o Python, então é bastante difícil aferir o que está tentando fazer. Poderia elaborar um [mcve]?

Comment: Cara como o Anderson disse acima, esta sintax não existe em python, no máximo seria  ```lista[ ['Temperatura', 250, k]['Temperatura Maxima', 310, k]] ``` e você pode manipular os valores desta maneria ```lista[0] # traz toda a lista que esteje na posição 0``` ```lista[0][1] # Traz o seguno valor da lista que esta na posição 0.```

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde,

Sua pergunta não ficou clara o suficiente, porém pelas tags e pelo tipo de dados na lista irei supor de algoritmo python com uma lista de string.

Existem diversas maneiras de você transformar os sua string em uma lista:

- Utilizando o split: esse método da próprio tipo string recebe um caractere e divide sua string nas posições que o caractere se encontra. No seu caso não seria o que você procura pois o caractere que poderia se utilizado seria o ' '(espaço) e teria a seguinte saída.

  `'Temperatura final = 250 k'.split(' ')
  ['Temperatura', 'final', '=', '250', 'k']`
- Substring: poderia ser utilizado uma substring, no qual você especificaria as posições de cada grupo, porém você deveria fazer a divisão por cada grupo e se a string mudasse e seu tamanho alterasse, você não pegaria a informação correta.

  `'Temperatura final = 250 k'[:17]
  'Temperatura final'`
- Regex: esta seria a opção mais comoda no qual você poderá montar a estrutura de grupos desejada, definindo os padrões de cada grupo e os extraindo ao mesmo tempo.

  `s = r'Temperatura final = 250 k'
   re.findall(r'(.*)\s+=\s+(\d+)\s+(\w+)',s)
  [('Temperatura final', '250', 'k')]`

O único porém é quando é executado a busca de mais de um grupo simultâneo o findall retorna uma tupla com os grupo encontrados dentro de uma lista. Assim você deverá pegar a primeira posição da lista resposta, que será uma tupla e converter para uma lista.

Como ficaria o resultado final:

```
import re
listafinal = [
    ['Temperatura final, 250, k'],
    ['Temperatura Minima, 120, k'],
    ['Temperatura Maxima, 310, k']
]

padrao = r'(.*)\s+=\s+(\d+)\s+(\w+)'
resultado = list()

for texto in listafinal:
   resultado.append(list(re.findall(padrao, texto)[0]))
```

Comment: Criei algo assim pra conseguir resolver! Obrigado pelo help!